# How to add query criteria in @query Notation, Is that possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<SalutationMst, Long> {

    @Query("select id from SalutationMst where name=:name and code=:code and id=:id")
    Optional<Long> findByAny(String name,String code,Long id);


}
```

Is there is any way to add criteria from here by looking values in name,code,id. This repository is calling from controller.

Comment: Be more specific in your question

Comment: Seems this article solve your problem https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 @Query("select e.id from SalutationMst e where e.name=:name and e.code=:code and e.id=:id")
 Optional<Long> findByAny(@Param("name")String name,@Param("code")String code,@Param("id")Long id);
```

Another way:

```
 @Query("select e.id from SalutationMst e where e.name=?1 and e.code=?2 and e.id=?3")
 Optional<Long> findByAny(String name,String code,Long id);
```

No need to remove the params, just pass the 'Null' values

```
 select e.id from SalutationMst e where (e.name=?1 or ?1 is null) and e.code=?2 and e.id=?3
```

Comment: if String name is blank then i need to remove that condition from query how?Is that possible

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Specification in this case [check this](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification)
You may dynamically form predicates here.

If that seems a little complex, You may use Query by Example [check this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/query-by-example.html)
by default it will ignore null fields.

Comment: This is use full. And tell me one more thing by this Example<> can we do a search same as "like" in query?

Comment: `ExampleMatcher matcher  = ExampleMatcher.matching().withMatcher("pathToAttribute", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.contains());
    

Example.of(carrierFreightNumber, matcher);`